# How to use a webform key more than once.

Tags: webforms

We are using webform and on submit sending the result to an API. We have a drop down that loads on context. We need use form_key twice, one for each dropdown but Drupal will now allow us to, is there a way to use form_key on two fields?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need form_key twice in the $form on the page? Simply add a custom submit handler to the form and create whatever custom $form_state or values you want to pass on to the remote API ... and let webform store the data as it wants seperate from what you send to the API.